# QGIS Processing Plugin: automatically set "edit rendering styles for outputs"

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-processing

I have created a Processing plug-in with the help of `plugin builder`.
To finalize the outputs, I have created `.qml` files to be loaded in the "Edit Rendering Styles for Outputs..." dialog.
However, I need to do this manually after having loaded the `plug-in`, is there a way to set this automatically from within the plug-in code ?
I am working with QGIS 3.18.3

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- In `processAlgorithm` method, change all `dest_id` to `self.dest_id`.
- Add the following script to your algorithm class.

  ```
  def postProcessAlgorithm(self, context, feedback):

      output_layer= QgsProcessingUtils.mapLayerFromString(self.dest_id, context)
      output_layer.loadNamedStyle("path/to/qml_file.qml", True)

      return {}
  ```

Comment: Simple, yet effective! Many thanks!